# Watch/observe number of DOM children in Vue

Tags: vue.js, observable

Given a typical Vue component with `slot` usage:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "VueComponent"
}
</script>
```

Is there any possible way to implement an observer/watcher that keeps track of number of DOM children inside `slot`? I need to know whenever a child is added/removed inside the component.

Comment: It's funny that I often find the answer right after posting my question here. Anw...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what I find useful for my problem is [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). We need to attach an observer to the component after it is mounted, add callback handler and disconnect the observer before the component is destroyed (unmounted in Vue3).

Here is an working example written in Vue 2.6

```
<template>
  <div ref="container">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "VueComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      observer: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initObserver()
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.observer) this.observer.disconnect()
  },
  methods() {
    handleChildrenChanged() {

    },
    initObserver() {
      config = {
        subtree: false,
        childList: true,
        // it's better if you can detect children change by id
        // this can reduce number of updates
        // attributes: true,
        // attributeList: [ 'id' ] 
      }
      const self = this
      const callback = () => {
        self.$nextTick(() => {
          self.handleChildrenChanged()
        })
      }
      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
      observer.observe(this.$refs.container, config)
      this.observer = observer
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You can find another usage of MutationObserver in Vue here: https://dev.to/sammm/using-mutationobserver-and-resizeobserver-to-measure-a-changing-dom-element-in-vue-3jpd